# order based on two nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In neo4j i want to order the results based on ContactId and LookedupStatus in descending order.

This query orders the results based on ContactId only

```
   MATCH (p:Contact)<-[:RELATIONSHIP]-(d:GroupMember) 
   WHERE toint(d.GroupId) = 55 
   and p.EmailId<>''
   RETURN p
   order by toint(p.ContactId) desc
```

How to modify the above query so that it orders on both p.ContactId and p.LookedupStatus

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the sort conditions:

```
UNWIND [ {a:3, b:2, c: 1}, {a:1, b:2, c: 2}, 
         {a:1, b:1, c: 3}, {a:3, b:1, c: 4} ] as n
RETURN n ORDER BY n.a DESC, 
                  n.b ASC
```